# Twitter TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: json, pandas, twitter, mining

I am trying to follow a tutorial on twitter data mining, the steps emulated as as follows:

```
 tweets_data_path = '/home/ambijat/ipythonnbs/twitter/twitter_data.txt'
    tweet_data = []
 tweets_file = open(tweets_data_path, "r")
for line in tweets_file:
try:
    tweet = json.loads(line)
    tweet_data.append(tweet)
except:
    continue
```

And then:

```
   tweets = pd.DataFrame()
  tweets['text'] = map(lambda tweet: tweet['text'], tweet_data)
   tweets['lang'] = map(lambda tweet: tweet['lang'], tweet_data)
  tweets['country'] = map(lambda tweet: tweet['place']['country'] if tweet['place'] != None else None, tweet_data)
```

And the outcome is:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
  <ipython-input-9-a42fce63cc05> in <module>()
     1 tweets = pd.DataFrame()
----> 2 tweets['text'] = map(lambda tweet: tweet['text'], tweet_data)
  3 tweets['lang'] = map(lambda tweet: tweet['lang'], tweet_data)
     4 tweets['country'] = map(lambda tweet: tweet['place']['country'] if tweet['place'] != None else None, tweet_data)

   <ipython-input-9-a42fce63cc05> in <lambda>(tweet)
  1 tweets = pd.DataFrame()
   ----> 2 tweets['text'] = map(lambda tweet: tweet['text'], tweet_data)
  3 tweets['lang'] = map(lambda tweet: tweet['lang'], tweet_data)
  4 tweets['country'] = map(lambda tweet: tweet['place']['country'] if tweet['place'] != None else None, tweet_data)

   TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Could someone please help me in locating my mistake I am practically novice.

Comment: Can you add sample of your data?

Comment: Link doesnt work - Error 404

Comment: [https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9u5ditNO9FEMzVleHFmMXhUVTQ] I have tested it again please see.

Comment: Sorry, I have `]` in link, now it works.

Comment: I am not sure this is the second try, hope it helps [https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=F546757F71A8D8D9!22075&authkey=!ALJUD7m6S6Xe7Xw&ithint=file%2ctxt]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also directly pass `tweet_data` list to [`json_normalize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html):

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize    
tweets = json_normalize(tweet_data)[["text", "lang", "place.country"]]

    text                                                lang    place.country
0   This not the 1st. They hv 1 in Faisalabad alre...   en      پاکستان
1   RT @TOLOnews: Pakistan Trying To Create Third ...   en      NaN
2   RT @murtazasolangi: JuD establishes parallel "...   en      NaN
```

Comment: Thanks to all, I have figured out one more thing, the real reason why my pasted quote did not work has been that I had some garbage data (numbers) in first two lines of the text file collecting all the tweets. I removed these first two lines and then the code worked just fine.

Comment: I have a little more task at hand, I want to save the output from running the cell `tweets['country']` into text file.
It gives me output something like this:

       The output is truncated. The output gets suppressed, I want entire output.
I am using 
                   `%%capture cap --no-stderr
               tweets['country']
               with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
               f.write(cap.stdout)`